# Run Maven tests with -Dmaven.surefire.debug and -DforkMode=never

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a project with Maven and Surefire plugin v. 2.11. 
To run single tests I am using `-Dtest=TestClass#testMethod` and `-DforkMode=never` (without `DforkMode=never` I can't run tests because of lack of space for object heap). I got used to it and it was working for me fine.
So I am running:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod test -DforkMode=never
```

and test is run fine.

But when I am running

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod -Dmaven.surefire.debug test -DforkMode=never
```

it just skips debug "waiting" part and the test is being executed (I am unable to connect using IDE).
`mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test` works for me fine with other project (where I don't need to care about fork mode).

Any ideas why the combination of `forkMode=never` and `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: can't you just run with -DskipTests ?

Comment: well no... I want to run the test, not skip it. I want to run single test with debug and fork mode = never

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: -Dspecific_method=method_name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The property `maven.surefire.debug` is setting the `debugForkedProcess` parameter of the surefire plugin.

The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#debugForkedProcess) for this parameter reads as follows:

> Attach a debugger to the **forked** JVM. If set to "true", the process will suspend and wait for a debugger to attach on port 5005. If set to some other string, that string will be appended to the argLine, allowing you to configure arbitrary debuggability options (without overwriting the other options specified through the argLine parameter).

So it will only debug forked JVMs, which explains why it doesn't work when the tests aren't being forked. It isn't able to setup the debugging of a non-forked JVM process that is already running.

**Use `mvnDebug`**

What you can do instead is use [`mvnDebug`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html), which allows you to debug the maven process itself - and as your tests are not being forked those as well.

i.e. instead of `mvn -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod test -DforkMode=never` you would execute `mvnDebug -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod test -DforkMode=never`. By default it will listen on port 8000 when it starts maven.

Comment: cool! I didn't know, that debugger can be attached to forked JVM only. working now, thanks for help