# Remote debugging with mvnDebug, doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: maven, debugging

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853683/286795, I'm trying to remotely debug a Maven project using mvnDebug and IntelliJ. However, the execution doesn't stop on my breakpoints.
To reproduce a simple Hello World example:

On the local machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/LableOrg/java-maven-junit-helloworld.git
cd java-maven-junit-helloworld
mvnDebug test
```

On the remote machine:

1. Open IntelliJ
2. Check out from Version Control->Git, set URL: https://github.com/LableOrg/java-maven-junit-helloworld.git, Clone
3. Open the project
4. Open Hello.java, set a breakpoint at the line that says `printer.println(HELLO);`
5. Run->Debug...->Edit Configurations..., Add New Configuration->Remote
6. Set Debugger mode: Attach, Transport: Socket, Host:, Port:8000
7. Apply, Debug

The tests will now run WITHOUT stopping at the breakpoint. Why?

Answer (score 12):

While running the `mvnDebug` command, use `-DforkMode=never`.

so your maven command will look like this:

```
mvnDebug -DforkMode=never -Dmaven.surefire.debug clean install
```

For more info on `-DforkMode=never`, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451553/run-maven-tests-with-dmaven-surefire-debug-and-dforkmode-never)

Comment: I think that this is `forkCount` now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12598562/405326.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `debugForkedMode` of `maven-surefire-plugin` to true

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
   <configuration>
      <debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Then add another remote debug configuration on port 5005.

Comment: Hi @amseager, Thank for the help. It works for me ! I have another question. Why I need to start 2 remote debug : 1 on port 5005 and another on 8000 ?

Comment: Hi. These are default ports for maven surefire plugin and mvnDebug respectively. Actually, I found it easier not to use mvnDebug but simply mvn (f.e. "mvn test" or via "test" goal in IDEA's maven toolbar). In that case you only need to start remote debug on port 5005 (but "debugForkedProcess" flag should be set to true anyway). Works for maven 3.6.1, dunno about older versions.